Angular 14 / NGIX Server | White screen on Firefox and Chrome
Recently we are having issues with the deployment of our Angular App. Its angular 14, running in a ngix server.
The issue arises when we do BGD (Blue green deployment, we have two prod environments, we switch between them to have 0 downtime, while one is serving the other is building the new version), our Angular app freezes on a white screen, just loading what is in the index.html (cookies popup, Analytics, etc). Sometimes works on Firefox but not on Chrome, or viceversa.
Now it only fails on Firefox and I got some extra insights, looks like when tries to load runtime.js the HTTP call fails with error: NS_ERROR_CORRUPTED_CONTENT.
I checked the file exists and it does, and the content is complete, seems correct. The MIME types are correct to for js files. The weirdest thing is that if switch the boolean sourceMap on the angular.json, it works again. Its not that it works being true, it just works again when we switch from true to false or viceversa.
I'm running out of ideas or thing to check, and I can't find info related with this.
If anyone had a similar issue or haves any insight or different thing to test I would appreciate the info. thanks!
I checked the file exists and it does, and the content is complete, seems correct. The MIME types are correct to for js files. The weirdest thing is that if switch the boolean sourceMap on the angular.json, it works again. Its not that it works being true, it just works again when we switch from true to false or viceversa.
